# Appending html create inputs with different order

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html with three inputs like:

[image]

Html:

```
<div class="form-group" id="item-list0">
    <label>Role Name</label>
    <input asp-for="RoleClaimList[0].Role.Name" class="form-control roles" />
    <div id="claim-list0">
        <label>Claim Type</label>
        <input asp-for="RoleClaimList[0].ClaimList[0].Type" class="form-control claimType" />
        <label>Claim Value</label>
        <input asp-for="RoleClaimList[0].ClaimList[0].Value" class="form-control claimValue" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="addClaim">Add another claim</a>
</div>

<a href="#" id="add">Add another role</a>
```

As you can see I have two actions "Add another role" and "Add another claim"

If I press add another claim it just replicate `Claim Type` and `Claim Value` inputs

If I press "Add another role" it add all inputs again

I achieve that with Jquery as:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var roleIndex = 0;
        var claimIndex = 0;
        $("#add").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            roleIndex = roleIndex + 1;
            claimIndex = 0;
            var n = '<div id="item-list' + roleIndex +'"><label>Role Name</label><input class="form-control" name="RoleClaimList[' + roleIndex + '].Role.Name" /></div>'
            var m = '<div id="claim-list' + roleIndex+'"><label>Claim Type</label><input class="form-control"  name="RoleClaimList[' + roleIndex + '].ClaimList[' + claimIndex + '].Type" />'
            var c = '<label>Claim Value</label><input class="form-control"  name="RoleClaimList[' + roleIndex + '].ClaimList[' + claimIndex + '].Value" />  </div>'
            $("#item-list" + (roleIndex - 1) + "").append(n);
            $("#claim-list" + (roleIndex - 1) + "").append(m);
            $("#claim-list" + (roleIndex - 1) + "").append(c);
        });

        $("#addClaim").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            claimIndex = claimIndex + 1;
            var m = '<div id="claim-list' + claimIndex + '"><label>Claim Type</label><input class="form-control"  name="RoleClaimList[' + roleIndex + '].ClaimList[' + claimIndex + '].Type" />'
            var c = '<label>Claim Value</label><input class="form-control"  name="RoleClaimList[' + roleIndex + '].ClaimList[' + claimIndex + '].Value" />  </div>'
            $("#claim-list" + (claimIndex - 1) + "").append(m);
            $("#claim-list" + (claimIndex - 1) + "").append(c);
        });

    });
</script>
```

If I add claim it works correctly. Problem start when I add a new role. It should replicate first tree inputs in same order of first one, but it is creating `Claim Type` first then `Claim Value` and finally `Role Name` as this picture:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong there? Regards

Comment: Consider how your logic is using both `roleIndex` and `claimIndex` to determine which `#claim-list` to append to.  You're going to be duplicating claim-list ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong is that you are appending your new `#item-list1` div into the existing `#item-list0`, making it a nested structure.

Same goes to your `#claim-list`, it became a nested structure:

```
#item-list0
⤷ #claim-list0
  ⤷ #claim-list1
  ⤷ #claim-list2
  ⤷ #claim-list3
⤷ #item-list1
⤷ #item-list2
⤷ #item-list3
```

What you should do instead is to append them outside:

1. Append new `#item-listx` to `<body></body>` or whatever parent element.
2. Append new `#claim-list` to its corresponding `#item-list`s.

So it would be your intended structure:

```
#item-list0
⤷ #claim-list0
⤷ #claim-list1
⤷ #claim-list2

#item-list1
⤷ #claim-list0
⤷ #claim-list1
⤷ #claim-list2
```

And if you look at it, there comes a few more problems with your code:

1. You will have duplicated `id`.
2. `claimIndex` will not work properly because you reset it every time `#add` is clicked (what happens if I click "addClaim" to previous roles after I add new role?)

Below is a sample code that works properly (I think, may not actually be your use case). I have restructured it so that it can be easily understood without much explanation. Please edit as needed to suit your actual code base:

```js
var roleIndex = 0;

$('#add')
  .on('click', addRole) // Add onclick handler
  .trigger('click');    // Trigger it on execution to create the first set

function addRole(){
  roleIndex += 1;

  // Set `claimIndex` here, not outside of the scope
  // because you need it in each separate added role
  // so that the claimIndex of each role can correctly counts independently
  var claimIndex = 0,
      roleClaimList = 'RoleClaimList[' + roleIndex + ']';

  var $itemList = $('<div></div>')
    .addClass('form-group')
    .attr('id', 'item-list-' + roleIndex);

  var $roleLabel = $('<label></label>')
    .text('Role Name')
    .appendTo($itemList);

  var $roleInput = $('<input>')
    .addClass('form-control roles')
    .attr('asp-for', roleClaimList + '.Role.Name')
    .appendTo($itemList);

  var $addClaimButton = $('<a></a>')
    .text('Add another claim')
    .attr('href', '#')
    .addClass('addClaim')
    .on('click', addClaim)
    .appendTo($itemList);

  $addClaimButton.trigger('click');

  $itemList.insertBefore(this);

  // Create this function here, not outside
  // because it needs the `claimIndex` in scope
  function addClaim(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    claimIndex += 1;

    var $claimGroup = $('<div></div>')
      .attr('id', 'claim-list-' + roleIndex + '-' + claimIndex)
      .insertBefore($addClaimButton);

    var $typeLabel = $('<label></label')
      .text('Claim Type')
      .appendTo($claimGroup);

    var $typeInput = $('<input>')
      .addClass('form-control claimType')
      .attr('asp-for', roleClaimList + '.ClaimList[' + claimIndex + '].Type')
      .appendTo($claimGroup);

    var $valueLabel = $('<label></label')
      .text('Claim Value')
      .appendTo($claimGroup);

    var $valueInput = $('<input>')
      .addClass('form-control claimValue')
      .attr('asp-for', roleClaimList + '.ClaimList[' + claimIndex + '].Value')
      .appendTo($claimGroup);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group" id="item-list-0"></div>
<a href="#" id="add">Add another role</a>
```

To know more about scoping, read this [amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).